# Grails - download data on page load, get on ajax call

Tags: ajax, grails, proxy

I have an ajax call to an external API I need to make on page load that downlads json data. Normally I would just call the API directly from the page to the external site, but I need the site to work on IE8, so I'm proxying the API call through grails to avoid origin issues.

What I'm looking to do is start downloading the json data to the server when the action is called to load the page, cache the json data, and provide the data via an ajax call when javascript calls the grails server on page load. The obvious issue is making sure the proxy api call only returns when the data has finished downloading to the server from the external site. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the jQuery plugin: [Cross-Domain AJAX for IE8 and IE9](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)

Then you can do a standard $.ajax() with IE8 and none of that is necessary.